# Using SqlBulkCopy with a partitioned view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I want to use `SqlBulkCopy` to get data from my .Net app into SQL Server, to improve performance.

But the DBA has made all the really big tables (the ones where `SqlBulkCopy` would really shine) into partitioned views.

There are no articles on SO about this, and there are questions on the web but none of them are answered.

I'm looking for a workaround to make this work.

Note:

I'm going to edit my question tomorrow with the exact error message and whatever other details I can bring. None of the questions on the internet include the error that SQL Server returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that SQL Server has no support for partitioned views - partitioned tables are something different - likely the view is read only and you msut write to the underlying correct table. Simple like that.

Possibly also that there is an instead of trigger on the view that is not triggered by bulk copy. That said, it is pretty bad to sql bulk copy to a table (sql builk copy is written by someone who loves non scalable scenarios) so the best practives are to sql bulk copy to a temporary table then insert into the final table (avoiding the bad locking code in sql bulk copy). In this case the trigger fires-

Comment: So my DBA calls it by the wrong name, wonderful. I'll research it now that I know what it actually is.